# Writing spark dataframe to ascii JSON

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe

I am attempting to write a spark dataframe as JSON file; this will eventually be written out into MapR JSON DB table.

```
grp_small.toJSON.write.save("<path>")
```

This seems to write JSON file in snappy.parquet format. How do I force it to write it as a readable JSON (txt format) ?

Comment: It might be using snappy compression and parquet format due to the sqlContext configuration that you've set.
`sqlContxt.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec","snappy")`
To avoid this, please use `grp_small.toJSON.saveAsTextFile("path")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write dataframe to `json` which contains each row as readable `json` in each line.

```
grp_small.write.json("path to output")
```

Hope this hepls!