# Writing spark dataframe to readable JSON with dataframe.toJSON.write.save

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I had asked this question below:

[Writing spark dataframe to ascii JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519671/writing-spark-dataframe-to-ascii-json/49519818#49519818)

However, the suggestion provided runs into a bug on the cluster. 
The error is: "

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException:    org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 2
```

at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:687)
"

Is there a workaround to write out readable JSON with dataframe.toJSON.write.save ?

Comment: That error suggests that you have different versions of the class between driver and workers. You'll have to update the code on your workers to have the same versions as your driver's.

Comment: Can you share how did you run on the cluster?

Comment: grp_small.write.json("path to output") as you had suggested, where "path to output" is the path maprfs folder that I have access to.

Comment: what spark-submit command did you used ?

Comment: I am inside spark-shell

Answer (score 0):

You should call `saveAsTextFile` in place of `save`.

> dataframe.toJSON.saveAsTextFile("path")

Comment: Which version of spark is saveAsTextFile available under df.toJSON.write? I do not see it in 2.0.1.

Comment: I am assuming that your suggestion is for Python. I am using Scala and it does not have saveAsTextFile method under .toJSON.write

Comment: Corrected the snippet above. Please check now.